# Keyboard not appearing for making entry to text box

Tags: jquery, android, textbox, keyboard

I have a text box which takes file name to read the specific file from sdcard.  This text box is using jQuery and html5,javascript. So its loading webview on andorid.

But when I launch the activity, I am not able to get the soft keypad of the device.
So i  am unable to enter anything.

I have tested this on Samsung Galaxy tab,samsung galaxy Ace, and S2 (all android).

I have attached the screen shot of it too[image]

Thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 0):

In Your Activity, please confirm `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` is provided or not. If you are using phonegap and jquery mobile, it is must to provide. And also check `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`.